# Compound inequality in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, dataframe

This is a generalized function I want to use to check if each row of a dataframe follows a specific trend in column values.

```
def follows_trend(row):
    trend = None
    if row[("col_5" < "col_6" < "col_4" < "col_1" < "col_2" < "col_3")]:
        trend = True        
    else:
        trend = False
    return trend
```

I'll apply it like this

```
df_trend = df.apply(follows_trend, axis=1)
```

When I do, it returns all `True` when there are clearly some rows that should return `False`. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the inequality I used or the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

The compound comparisons don't "expand out of" the dict lookup. `"col_5" < "col_6" < "col_4" < "col_1" < "col_2" < "col_3"` will be evaluated first, producing `False` because the strings aren't sorted - so your if statement is actually `if row[(False)]:`. You need to do this:

```
if row["col_5"] < row["col_6"] < row["col_4"] < row["col_1"] < row["col_2"] < row["col_3"]:
```

If you have a lot of these expressions, you should probably extract this to a method that takes `row` and a list of the column names, and uses a loop for the comparisons. If you only have one, but want a somewhat more nice-looking version, try this:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = (row[c] for c in ("col_5", "col_6", "col_4", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3"))
if a < b < c < d < e < f:
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can reorder the column names, use the `diff` function to check the difference along the rows and compare the result with `0`:

```
(df[["col_5", "col_6", "col_4", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]]
   .diff(axis=1).drop('col_5', 1).gt(0).all(1))
```

*Example*:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2], "B": [3,1], "C": [4,2]})
df

#   A   B   C
#0  1   3   4
#1  2   1   2

df.diff(axis=1).drop('A', 1).gt(0).all(1)

#0     True
#1    False
#dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `query` for this. See example below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
print df
print df.query('col2>col3>col1') # query can accept a string with multiple comparisons.
```

results in

```
     col1      col2      col3
0 -0.788909  1.591521  1.709402
1 -1.563310  1.188993  2.295683
2 -1.572323 -0.600015 -1.518411
3  1.786051  0.303291 -0.344720
4  0.756029 -0.393941  1.059874
       col1      col2      col3
2 -1.572323 -0.600015 -1.518411
```